# Javascript function to remove leading dot

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have a javascript string which have a leading dot. I want to remove the leading dot using javascript replace function. I tried the following code.

```
var a = '.2.98»';
document.write(a.replace('/^(\.+)(.+)/',"$2"));
```

But this is not working. Any Idea?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following replaces a dot in the beginning of a string with an empty string leaving the rest of the string untouched:

```
a.replace(/^\./, "")
```

Comment: As I said in other comments, this is not a good idea at all. There is no need for regular expressions here, it's slower and inefficient.

Comment: @ColinHebert such a marginal micro optimization is definitely not worth conditionals. the document.write will be 99% of the actual work done here anyway.

Comment: @Esailija, it's not optimisation, it's common sense. You could also do ten loops on every char in the string before doing the regex, removing those 10 loops wouldn't be called optimisation but common sense. Using a regular expression engine to remove one character is way more than an overkill. All it actually does here is preventing one line of code (the `if` line).

Comment: BTW, here is what "doesn't worth it": `if (a.charAt(0)=='.') a = a.substr(1);`. So yes, for any person who would read that topic thinking "oh it's okay I can just use regexes everywhere", I say here "Here, it's slower and inefficient".

Comment: @Esailija I tend to agree with Colin here - learning the best way to do things for sensibility and performance is not micro optimization; it's learning your trade. Hacking up your code and adding a bunch of unreadable garbled garbage to save 10ms is micro optimization.

Comment: @rlemon as I said, there is no performance or efficiency to be gained here, so the extra conditional is in no way justified with those arguments. 10ms is pretty substantial performance difference, btw (centi optimization :D).

Comment: @Esailija I meant 10ms for the page, not the script :P also, how can you say there is no performance difference here? on a simple regex it can be seen... I can't begin to imagine how bad a complex regex would be. http://jsperf.com/regex-vs-charat

Answer (score 8):

Don't do regexes if you don't need to.

A simple `charAt()` and a `substring()` or a `substr()` (only if `charAt(0)` is `.`)  will be enough.

---

**Resources:**

- [developer.mozilla.org: `charAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt)
- [developer.mozilla.org: `substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)
- [developer.mozilla.org: `substr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)

Comment: The string sometimes may not have the dot. Thats why I am using regex.

Comment: That's why you should use `charAt()`, to check if there is a dot or not. There is absolutely no need for a regular expression engine to be used there.

Comment: It is important to note that w3schools is a HORRIBLE reference to give anyone. http://w3fools.com/

Comment: @rlemon, thank you, I don't really use that site at all, I just needed some quick documentation to give as resources. I'll change the links though, to avoid sending people in the wrong place.

Comment: It's the w3school google plague.. it usually is the first result unless you explicitly block it.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is wrong.

```
var a = '.2.98»';
document.write(a.replace('/^\.(.+)/',"$1"));
```

You tried to match `(.+)` to the leading dot, but that doesn't work, you want `\.` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple:

```
if (a.charAt(0)=='.') {
  document.write(a.substr(1));
} else {
  document.write(a);
}
```

Comment: No need to do an `indexOf`. With `indexOf` you'll look every character until you get a dot, but in the end you're only interested in the first one.