# Remove dot . sign from the end of the string

Tags: javascript

I have this requirement where it is required to remove only the last `.` dot sign from a string.

Say if we have var `str = 'abcd dhfjd.fhfjd.';` i need remove the final dot sign which would output `abcd dhfjd.fhfjd` .

I found this link ( [Javascript function to remove leading dot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106610/javascript-function-to-remove-leading-dot) ) which removes the first dot sign but I am new to this whole thing and could not find any source on how to remove a specific last character if exists.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Single dot:

```
if (str[str.length-1] === ".")
    str = str.slice(0,-1);
```

Multiple dots:

```
while (str[str.length-1] === ".")
    str = str.slice(0,-1);
```

Single dot, regex:

```
str = str.replace(/\.$/, "");
```

Multiple dots, regex:

```
str = str.replace(/\.+$/, "");
```

Comment: show where should i put variable contains string with dots, thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
if(str.lastIndexOf('.') === (str.length - 1)){
    str = str.substring(0, str.length - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will remove all trailing dots, and may be easier to understand for a beginner (compared to the other answers):

```
while(str.charAt(str.length-1) == '.')
{
    str = str.substr(0, str.length-1);
}
```